# Updating computers over unsafe connections

Tags: man-in-the-middle

If an attacker manages to get control of one of the devices managing or routing internet traffic along or on my network, e.g, a compromised router or femtocell/IMSI-catcher for mobile internet, how do I go about safely and securely updating my computers (e.g, apt-get update apt-get upgrade)?

I realize doing this over tor might be a good idea, but I need to install tor in the first place and so need to connect to the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any good software updating process will be using [digital signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) to ensure integrity. Every digital signature works by performing a mathematical operation on a hash of the files using a secret key known only to the operators of the software update infrastructure. The result of this operation is the creation of a digital signature. It's easy to verify that the signature came from a given secret key, but it is designed to be extremely difficult (impossible with current technology) to forge it.

The `apt` updater used in Debian-based systems automatically verifies digital signatures. If an attacker on the network modifies the update files, they will not be able to forge a matching signature. This will be detected and the malicious updates will not be installed. The worst an attacker can do is prevent you from updating. They cannot replace your updates with malicious ones without being detected.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. It seems to me that your post addresses updates before they are installed. I.e., the udpdate software checks the signature before installing and if it matches, installs/updates the software. I have read in an older issue of Linux Pro Magazine a mention of "malicious modification of software on the fly", i.e., after the signature is checked and the download is started. Is this something that can happen?

Comment: @user942937 It's not possible for a network attacker to modify the software after it has been checked.